# How can I extend the Gutenberg table block transform to allow colspans/rowspans on pasted table <td> elements?

Tags: filters, html, block-editor, table

I'm trying to allow users to paste (relatively) simple tables into Gutenberg. The editor converts the raw HTML fine but strips out any attributes/classes. For the most part this is good - I want to ensure the markup is clean - but it strips out the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes too.

Looking into the table block in the Gutenberg repo on GitHub and block filters in the Guenberg Handbook on wordpress.org, I've put together the following:

```
const { getPhrasingContentSchema } = wp.blocks;

// Partially defines what's allowed in a table when pasted.
// Copied from the core table block file in the Gutenberg repo.
const tableContentPasteSchema = {
    tr: {
        children: {
            th: {
                children: getPhrasingContentSchema(),
            },
            td: {
                children: getPhrasingContentSchema(),

                // This is the only new part in the schema
                attributes: [ 'colspan', 'rowspan'],
            },
        },
    },
};

// Partially defines what's allowed in a table when pasted.
// Copied from the core table block file in the Gutenberg repo.
const tablePasteSchema = {
    table: {
        children: {
            thead: {
                children: tableContentPasteSchema,
            },
            tfoot: {
                children: tableContentPasteSchema,
            },
            tbody: {
                children: tableContentPasteSchema,
            },
        },
    },
};

// Overloads the table block transforms setting
function addTableBlockSpanAttributes( settings, name ) {
    if ( name !== 'core/table' ) {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        transforms: {
            from: [
                {
                    type: 'raw',
                    selector: 'table',
                    schema: tableSchema,
                },
            ],
        },
    });
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'my-plugin/transforms/table-block',
    addTableBlockSpanAttributes
);
```

(Code based on example here: https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype)

This all seems to be correct as far as I can tell, but any colspan/rowspans are stripped when pasted in. In addition, manually editing the block in the post HTML causes a block error which can only be resolved by removing the colspan/rowspan attribute.

It's worth noting that if I use the same code but allow `colspan` on a **`<span>`** inside the `<td>` that works absolutely fine (despite `<span colspan="2">` not being valid HTML).

What am I doing wrong? Is there another approach to overloading the `core/table` block's allowed attributes? Is there something else in core that's prohibiting `<td>` attributes?